# find array with increment key and insert into tab

Tags: php

I post a form with fields house address  city and state the form has multiple

basically i want to search the array with key _0 and key _1

i want to insert  the fields like  taking the index

for example for all index 0 house_address_0,city_0,state_0

```
insert into details(house_address,city,state) values(some address1,mumbai,maharashtra)
insert into details(house_address,city,state) values(some address2,chennai,tn)
for index 1 house_address_1,city_1,state_1
insert into details(house_address,city,state) values(some address3,bangalore,karnataka)
insert into details(house_address,city,state) values(some address4,trivandrum,kerala)
```

Below is array

```
Array
(

    [house_address_0] => Array
    (
        [0] => some address1
        [1] => some address2
    )

    [city_0] => Array
    (
        [0] => mumbai
        [1] => chennai
    )

    [state_0] => Array
    (
        [0] = maharashtra
        [1] = TN
    )

    [house_address_1] => Array
    (
       [0] => some address3
       [1] => some address4
    )

    [city_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => bangalore
        [1] => trivandrum
    )

    [state_1] => Array
    (
        [0] = karnataka
        [1] = kerala
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $house = $addresses['house_address_' . $i][0];
    $city = $addresses['city_' . $i][0];
    // ... etc ...
}
```